# saving information rails sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I am using rails 4.  When a client connects to my website for my first time (any link) I want to establish a session with the user that lasts for the next 20 years (or forever).  how do I establish this session (or cookie, im not sure) and keep track of what articles the user likes or dislikes (or just keep track of information).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite long topic, because you need to make some kind of sign in process for your clients so that your Web site is able to identify different users before saving their preferences. I would recommend you to have a look at *Michael Hartl’s Ruby on Rails Tutorial Book*, [Chapter 8: Sign in, sign out](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out#cha-sign_in_sign_out)

After having the sign in process ready, you can easily save their preferences into client/user table in database or some other table. When you have the sign in process established, you can create sessions that expire 20 years from now.

From the same chapter I just had a look on how to save data to a cookie that expires 20 years from now and is saved to a client’s browser:

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
```

`cookies.permanent` method call uses the method `20.years.from_now`

Answer (score 0):

correct thts can be done, 20 years means permanent only.
Just to add to @jyrkim answer, u can save cookies in encrypted
    *cookies.permanent.signed[:rem_token]  = "rem_token value"*
Hope it helps